# What's a good way to seed a random number generator to work with forking?

Tags: c++, c++11, random

Suppose I have a function `generateId` to generate random 64-bit integers. If I write `generateId` like this

```
uint64_t generateId() {
  static thread_local std::mt19937_64 rng{std::random_device{}()};
  return rng();
}
```

Then `rng` won't get reseeded after a fork. Running

```
int main() {
  std::cout << generateId() << "\n";
  if (fork() == 0) {
    std::cout << "child: " << generateId() << "\n";
  } else {
    std::cout << "parent: " << generateId() << "\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Will print the same number for child and parent.

Is there a way I can write `generateId` so that it reseeds for new processes but still remains performant.

Comment: Another problem with `std::random_device` is that it was broken in MinGW for years, and still is.

Comment: As a general rule, threads, non-POD cpp classes and `fork` do not play nicely together. cpp objects are not prepared for destructors to be called on objects where constructor has not been called (or generally bitwise copying them, which fork is doing), and `fork` is not working well with threads either - it even has a section of manpage dedicated to it. I suggest you stick with either multithreading or multipocessing.

Comment: Have you tried forking before the first call to the function?

Comment: @RSahu Doesn't really help in general if the real program needs a random number before the fork. Obviously that would work though yes

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - thanks. I'm actually using this method to seed: http://www.pcg-random.org/posts/simple-portable-cpp-seed-entropy.html

But to keep the question simple, let's just pretend like random_device is seeding well.

Comment: @SergeyA - That might be good advice in general. But the code I'm working on is a library that needs to work in both contexts.

Comment: you could write two random seeds to a file, then let each process grab one. This would prevent potential race conditions since they can lock access to the file

Comment: @SergeyA `fork` does no copying and it absolutely works fine in C++. Normal precautions still apply.

Comment: @rustyx what are you talking about? `fork()` does bitwise copying of all address space (alright, COW actually, but it doesn't matter in this context), including objects, including those of classes which are not trivially copyable - which usually (magically) works, but I have seen cases when it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with:

```
class TlsRandomNumberGenerator {
 public:
   TlsRandomNumberGenerator() {
     pthread_atfork(nullptr, nullptr, OnFork);
   }

   static uint64_t GenerateId() {
     return random_number_generator_();
   }
 private:
  static thread_local std::mt19937_64 random_number_generator_;

  static void OnFork() {
    random_number_generator_.seed(std::random_device{}());
  }
};

thread_local std::mt19937_64 TlsRandomNumberGenerator::random_number_generator_{
    std::random_device{}()};

uint64_t generateId() {
  static TlsRandomNumberGenerator rng;
  return TlsRandomNumberGenerator::GenerateId();
}
```

It will work with forking but also doesn't have the overhead of calling `getpid` for every number generation, which depending on the version of libc you're using may or may not be cached so can involve a performance penalty. See notes on [`getpid`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpid.2.html):

> From glibc version 2.3.4 up to and including version 2.24, the glibc
>          wrapper function for getpid() cached PIDs, with the goal of avoiding
>          additional system calls when a process calls getpid() repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
uint64_t generateId() {
   static pid_t mypid = 0;
   static std::unqiue_ptr<std::mt19937_64> rng;
   if( mypid != getpid() ) {
       rng.reset();
       mypid = getpid();
   }
   if( !rng )
      rng = std::make_unique<std::mt19937_64>(std::random_device{}());

   return (*rng)();
}
```

Note: this code is not thread safe, and I removed `thread_local` assuming you tried to solve `fork()` issue using it. If multithreading involved then proper locking is ncesessary as well as considerations on problems using `mutexes` or non-blocking primitives with `fork()`

Comment: Oh the joy of the race condition! You also removed `thread_local` from OP's code, and it doesn't seem like you preserved the semantic.

Comment: It is not clear if OP used `thread_local` to have different seed btw threads or he/she tried to solve `fork()` problem that way. If first OP can always return thread_local back (and proper synchronization), if later that is not necessary anymore. Based on code example there is no multithreading involved and do not have to assume it is.

Comment: I want it to work with threading, yes. @Slava - why use a unique_ptr instead of calling [seed](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/mersenne_twister_engine/seed/)?

Comment: @mickb no particular reason, I just did not look into interface and assumed that recreating object is simplest way to reseed. If that not the case you can change that, this code is to show the idea.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid a call to `getpid` each time?

Comment: Yes, there is a way to avoid a call to `getpid` each time, but it involves not forking.

Comment: @rnickb You could set a flag variable right before you call `fork` to indicate that the pid needs to be checked.